# Store encrypted data in console application

Tags: c++, encryption, console

I made a small console application game and I was wondering if I could be able to retain data such as highscores and setting in an encrypted file without allowing any modifications to it ? Is there a fast and easy way to achieve that in C++ ? Portability isn't important because I'm using windows api.

Comment: *"Is there a fast and easy way to achieve that in C++"* No, there really isn't. If somebody wants to fake their high-score, they'll find a way to do it. Spending time trying to prevent this is *wasting time*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the scores out as binary data will deter all but the most persistent fakers. Add a binary checksum e.g. md5 will detect when it gets changed.

Comment: Good idea, doesn't rely on static keys etc. To make it slightly harder, you can add a "salt", a bit of static, unchanging, text within your app and include that at the start of the md5 calculation (both during reads and writes, of course).